# git switch/checkout back to my own fork

Tags: git

I was working on my own branch in a fork - "myname/mybranch"

I switched to master fork onto another branch to do some work - "master/someotherbranch"

Now I want to switch back to "myname/mybranch "

I tried

```
git checkout myname/mybranch 
error: pathspec 'myname-mybranch' did not match any file(s) known to git.

git checkout myname myname/mybranch
error: pathspec 'myname' did not match any file(s) known to git.
```

I am just trying to checkout myname/mybranch again. How do I do this?

Thanks for the help !

Comment: Can you attach `git branch -a` output in the OP?

Comment: Too big to copy paste but it does not have my fork "myname"

Comment: Try this `git checkout myname mybranch`.

Comment: Ahh I had already tried that, it errors out. rror: pathspec 'myname' did not match any file(s) known to git.
error: pathspec 'mybranch' did not match any file(s) known to git.

Comment: Your first error message: `error: pathspec 'myname-mybranch' did not match ...` **does not match** your command: `git checkout myname/mybranch`. Note the slash versus the hyphen. What happened here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure `myBranch` exits in your remote. You can create a new `local/feature` from your `remote/myBranch`.

```
$ git remote -v        # see all the remotes 

$ git checkout -b feature <remote>/<branch>
e.g. git checkout -b feature myname/mybranch
```

---

#### Reset a new branch with remote/master:

```
$ git checkout -b temp
$ git reset --hard <remote>/master
```

Comment: error - fatal: Cannot update paths and switch to branch 'feature' at the same time.

Comment: Make sure your `remote` name is correct. `git remote -v` output ?

Answer (score 1):

```
git checkout -
```

This just goes back to the last branch you were. If you are just jumping between two branches, it will work. It came here from the bash command line `cd -` which just returns to the last directory.